# How can I create the 405 error

Tags: http, http-headers

I need to test 405 error page, but I have no idea how to create the 405 error.

Is there a way to reproduce 405 error on my site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP response status code `405` means `Method Not Allowed`. *This status code states that HTTP method was received and recognized by the server, but the server has rejected that particular method for the requested resource*.

The easiest way to stimulate the response code `405` is to either

1. Try to access a non-existing resource/URL
2. Try to access an existing resource without the proper permission.

Try the following example with an HTTP tool like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)

The following HTTP request tries to use `PUT` method on `/api/values/` without the right permission

```
PUT /api/values/1 HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/json
Host: localhost
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 12

"Some Value"
```

HTTP Response states code `405`

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 15 May 2013 02:38:57 GMT
Content-Length: 72

{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."}
```

Comment: I used ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(405) where in filter to test it.thanks again.